# How do I attach to multiple processes at once in Rider GUI?

Tags: rider

There's really not much more to the question than what's in the title. This is very simple in Visual Studio:

[image: VS Attach to Multiple]

Rider has a similar dropdown, but it immediately attaches to the first process I click. Oftentimes, I need to attach to these 6 processes at the same time.

Comment: You can't at the moment. Here's the ticket in their issue tracking: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10514